# Conda install package from github including requirements.txt

Tags: anaconda, jupyter, conda

I use a jupyter notebook as part of an anaconda installation. I'd like to install a Python package hosted on Github (i.e., via a `https://...` or `git://...` URL), along with all `requirements.txt` dependencies. This is a custom package developed in-house, not a package published to PyPI.

I'm not clear on whether I would want to do it in a `conda` or a `pip`/`virtualenv` environment, or how I would do it. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way but you can use Ipython console to install Github package (if supported by pip). Like for TwitterAPI you can use below command

```
!pip install TwitterAPI
```

Comment: This is not installing from `Github`, but from packages available with `pip`.